# How can I convert a function inside a class component to a function inside a function component

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in react, I'm following a tutorial that is made with a class component and I'm creating the Dapp using function components, I've followed to tutorials along but one of the functions didn't work. I want to make sure if the syntax is correct!  because stakeTokens function is not working !

***class components from the tutorial***

```
 stakeTokens = (amount) => {
this.setState({ loading: true })
this.state.daiToken.methods.approve(this.state.tokenFarm._address, amount).send({ from: this.state.account }).on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
  this.state.tokenFarm.methods.stakeTokens(amount).send({ from: this.state.account }).on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
    this.setState({ loading: false })
  })
})
```

}

***function component***

```
const stakeTokens = async (amount) => {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      await dTokens.methods
      .approve(FarmAddress, amount)
      .send({ from : accounts[0]})
      .on("transitionsHash", hash => {
         fTokens.methods
            .stakeTokens(amount)
            .send({from : accounts[0]})
            .on('error', function(error){
              console.log("it didn't work");
            });   
      });
};
```

Comment: Could you say what is not working?

Comment: stakeTokens function is not working!